# Adding data to variable results in a singleline string

Tags: string, powershell

I have a PowerShell PSCustomObject `$result` which I am filtering with multiple `Where-Object` statements.

```
$SatServers = $Global:result | Where-Object {$_ -like '*sat?2:00*' -and `
 $_.MaintenanceWindow -notmatch 'all.da.servers' -and `
  $_.Server -match "^IT"} | % {"{0}" -f $_.Server}

$SatServers += $Global:result | Where-Object {$_ -like '*sat?18:00*' -and `
 $_.MaintenanceWindow -notmatch 'all.da.servers' -and `
 $_.Server -match "^IT"} | % {"{0}" -f $_.Server}

$SatServers | Out-File d:\path\file.txt
```

If I output to the console or if I pipe to `Out-File` it looks great but when I send the output to a variable as seen above, I get output on a single line.

Is there something I'm missing in order to get a variable with a multiple line result?  -Thanks!

Comment: Accessing `$result` trough `$Global:` is (almost) ***never*** necessary. Please show us some context

Comment: Reason for the `$Global:` is I am creating that data in a child function within a larger function.

Comment: To the down voter, please post your comments so I'm aware of my mistakes as I am making an effort to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize `$SatServers` as an array first. You first call makes `$SatServers` a string-object and when you append (+=) a string to a string it simply adds it to the end of the last string.

String:

```
$string = "Hello"
$string += "Frode"

$string.GetType() | ft -AutoSize

IsPublic IsSerial Name   BaseType     
-------- -------- ----   --------     
True     True     String System.Object

$string
HelloFrode
```

Array:

```
$string = @()
$string += "Hello"
$string += "Frode"

$string.GetType() | ft -AutoSize

IsPublic IsSerial Name     BaseType    
-------- -------- ----     --------    
True     True     Object[] System.Array

$string
Hello
Frode
```

You could also have added a NewLine at the end of the string by doing the following change in your `Foreach-Object`-scriptblock (but personally I prefer the array-solution).

```
% { ("{0}" -f $_.Server) + [environment]::NewLine }
```

Comment: Finally got a chance to come back to this and I don't understand how I had some success (Result.txt files with multi-line output) and now using the Array method...I still get a single line of strings.

Comment: The array solution will give multiline. Remember to create the array first with `$result = @()`

Comment: Of course, I'm making two variables one for server names and the other for reboot times.  My workaround was to simply pipe the results from `Where-Object` to `Out-File` and I get multi-line output.  I'm puzzled because before I was getting desirable output.